# Inclusion homeomorphism?

Tags: differential-geometry

I´ve readen here some questions but never in the sense that I´m looking for.

My question is the inclusion is ever an homeomophism?

For $U$ an open set of a differentiable manifold $M$, I think the inclusion $i : U \to i(U) \subset M$ ever is an homeomorphism.

But for $P \subset M$ not necessarily an open subset, is $i : P \to i(P) \subset M$ an homeomorphism?

Thank you very much!

Comment: The inclusion $X\to X$ is a homeomorphism. In all other cases, inclusion can *at most* be a homeomorphism with its image (i.e., typically a proper subspace of the codomain)

Comment: You are correct about the fact that the inclusion map is a homeomorphism. For the second question again you are correct as the inclusion map is basically the restriction of Identity map in a certain domain.